# False Signals Counter - SuperTrend

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to write a piece of code in Pinescript to identify number of false signals generated by the supertrend indicator over a period of time, I have already got genuine signals counter now I am getting stuck in one particular line. I have basically defined my false signal as signal change during the course of a candle but reverts back to the current signal at the end of the candle.

I am getting stuck in this part. any assistance would be great. I am always getting false signals as 0.

```
for i=1 to 750
    changeCond = trend[i-1] != trend[i]
    if changeCond and  barstate.islast
        stsignal:=stsignal+1
    else if changeCond  and barstate.isnew != changeCond and barstate.islast
        falsesignal:=falsesignal+1
```

I can't find anything wrong with the logic or the code but output is always 0 false signals but the stsignals are accurate.